# Bash/shell code to run command on a list file of variables

Tags: bash, list, shell, repeat

so for starters i have the following, main process im running

```
for fname in (filename); do  
  ./$comma "$fname" (var1) (var2)  
  mv "$fname" "${fname}.fin"  
done
```

then i have a listfile of names looking like:

```
filename|var1|var2   
file1|9|1  
file2|8|3
```

etc...

would like to set it up where - when the master script goes to run the ./$comma script it reads from the listfile and populate the fname, var1, and var2 (per piped order) - right now i have a lot of repeated chunks of script like the above and would like to consolidate or clean it up for sure. Any help is appreciated - doesnt necessarily have to be a for;do loop - just as long as the script is ran on the right file with right args and gets renamed.

Comment: [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Thank you for this link - definitely helpful moving forward!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop you show isn't syntactically correct. You want a `while` loop, though, that uses the `read` command.

```
while IFS="|" read -r fname var1 var2; do
  ./"$comma" "$fname" "$var1" "$var2"
  mv "$fname" "$fname.fin"
done < filenames.txt
```

Comment: thank you so much, I do understand it wasnt syntactically correct for a reading of a file it was more a quick fix that turned into a frankenstein of a script.

Comment: I do want to ask - will this run always for every line in the filenames.txt? or will it "skip" those files that are not present when its being ran?  
`cd "$ftf"  `
  
`while IFS="|" read -r fname var1 var2; do  
  echo " Processing Comma MFIX: $fname" >> "$logfile"  
  ./"$comma" "$fname" "$var1" "$var2"  
  mv "$fname" "$fname.fin"  
done < comma_strlst.txt`